# owl-carousel not working in responsive mode

Tags: jquery-plugins, owl-carousel

I have an installation of owl on a site - works perfectly in desktop mode, but in mobile mode, the slides seems to disappear completely.

My site is at: ypt.co.il (the 4 blocks below the large main slider - looks first in dekstop mode).

This is the plugin code:

```
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:27,
        nav:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:3
            },
            992:{
                items:4
            }
        }
    });
```

Any input appreciated!

Comment: responsiveClass:true,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your carousel is not configured in mobile because of below condition.
check your condition where you are calling `res()`

```
if(!$('.toggleMenu').is(':visible')){
  res();
}
```

If condition will give **false** in mobile and true in desktop. That's why your carousel is not initialising.

You have to initialise your carousel in both mobile and desktop, so you can directly call `res()` after pageload.

```
$(function () {
  res();
});
```

It will work, I have tested on your website by modifying your js file.

Comment: what's the res() here ?

Comment: res() is a function where @kneidels is binding the owl carousel.  Basically $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({}) is present in res(); You can check on his website by debugging.