# Carousel images not showing in mobile device

Tags: html, jquery, css, carousel

I have carousel images. It is working properly with the laptop device but in mobile, images not showing. I'm using Owl Carousel v2.3.4. Could you please check my code below to see what is the error in my code? Thank you in advance.

```
<section class="app-screen-one" id="screenshot">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row mb-5">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
                                    <h3 class="font-weight-medium text-dark ">Let's See The App Screenshot</h3>
                                    <div><a href="#download" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Download Now</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-5" data-aos="fade-up">
                        <div class="app-screen-one__carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/carousel/signin.png" alt="screen">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/carousel/create-account.png" alt="screen">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/carousel/login.png" alt="screen">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/carousel/provider-profile.png" alt="screen">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/carousel/product-list.png" alt="screen">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/carousel/home-map.png" alt="screen">
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

Comment: send generated html (view source) from web page + JS that you are using, also anything that will help us to try to mimic your issues. we can't help you if we can't reproduce issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }
})
```

Are you add js for responsive to this carousel.

For more info : Visit https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Your question answered here : [owl-carousel not working in responsive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841930/owl-carousel-not-working-in-responsive-mode)

Comment: Please check this and also check browser console for showing any error...